# My foot is on my [native] heath, and my name is Trogdor

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/native) is one of those useless meta-tags that have no inherent meaning, but simply clutter up the tag space.

Can we burninate it please?

Comment: and it's very ambigus... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/native?sort=votes&pageSize=15

Comment: Cluttering up the tag space doesn't seem a good reason to remove it. I see it used in combination with c,c#, java where it makes sense. If anything the only troublesome tagged questions are those tagged with [tag:react-native]. Also that tag has 293 followers. Not sure if we need to worsen their ability to find questions they like to answer

Comment: 293 users that favorited the tag, 3.1K questions, 2 subject experts with a substantial number of answers.  No overlap, Alex Cohn covers [native] questions in JVM/Android and I cover CLR/.NET.  Neither of us is ever confused by "ambiguity", [native] is highly selective for the kind of interop you need to run native code.  Sure, you can easily make it harder for SO users to find us, it is however not obvious from the question what the point of that might be.

Comment: What Hans comment doesn't tell you is that there are .net native and something called Java Native Interface, both which have their own tags. [tag:.net-native] and [tag:jni]. The two "experts" in the native tag are answering questions about both technologies.

Comment: @johan I think you should change this to a cleanup/disambiguation request.

Comment: @Braiam: ".NET Native" is something else entirely.  [tag:native] in the context of .NET questions is nearly always talking about mixed-mode and interop, not the (extremely limited) compilation of managed code to machine language.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, that explains some users in the top answerers list that I couldn't figure out. So the native tag is worse. Yet another meaning the native tag is applied to. Instead of just .net-native and jni, also [tag:mixed-mode] and [tag:interop], both tags exists.